# How to upload a file to directory in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

i have an ActiveForm, and i want to add a field where the user can upload their photos.
the problem is that i don't have an attribute for the image in the users table and every 
input field in 'yii' expects a model and an attribute as follows.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'attribute')->input($platforms) ?>
```

i don't want to assign the image to any record nor i want to insert in in the database, i want it to be uploaded to a specific folder.

i have also checked the library kartik wrote, but also requires an attribute field.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28493615/how-to-upload-files-in-root-folder-in-yii2-advanced-template/36622990#36622990)  is step by step solution!!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Follow the official documentation

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/input-file-upload.md

Form Model

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

/**
* UploadForm is the model behind the upload form.
*/
class UploadForm extends Model
{
/**
 * @var UploadedFile|Null file attribute
 */
public $file;

/**
 * @return array the validation rules.
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['file'], 'file'],
    ];
}
}
?>
```

Form View

```
<?php
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

$form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput() ?>

<button>Submit</button>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Controller

Now create the controller that connects form and model together:

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\UploadForm;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
public function actionUpload()
{
    $model = new UploadForm();

    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
        $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');

        if ($model->validate()) {                
            $model->file->saveAs('uploads/' . $model->file->baseName . '.' . $model->file->extension);
        }
    }

    return $this->render('upload', ['model' => $model]);
}
}
?>
```

Instead of `model->load(...)` we are using `UploadedFile::getInstance(...)`. `[[\yii\web\UploadedFile|UploadedFile]]` does not run the model validation. It only provides information about the uploaded file. Therefore, you need to run validation manually via `$model->validate()`. This triggers the `[[yii\validators\FileValidator|FileValidator]]` that expects a file:

```
 $file instanceof UploadedFile || $file->error == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE //in code framework
```

If validation is successful, then we're saving the file:

```
 $model->file->saveAs('uploads/' . $model->file->baseName . '.' . $model->file->extension);
```

If you're using "basic" application template then folder uploads should be created under web.

That's it. Load the page and try uploading. Uplaods should end up in basic/web/uploads.

Comment: if i need to add one additional field and get its value after submit in controller. How can i do that.
suppose id have set the value id = 23 on active form. how to get this value on controller after submit

Comment: @Kshitiz - you'll have to load the POSTed variables separately. so you'll need $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) first and then assign the uploaded files to the file attribute.

Comment: could you also say how to save to db

Answer (score 15):

in your view

```
use kartik\widgets\ActiveForm;
use kartik\widgets\FileInput;

$form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]); //important
echo FileInput::widget([
                    'name' => 'filename',
                    'showUpload' => false,
                    'buttonOptions' => ['label' => false],
                    'removeOptions' => ['label' => false],
                    'groupOptions' => ['class' => 'input-group-lg']
                ]);
echo Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']);
ActiveForm::end();
```

in your controller

```
$file = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('filename');
$file->saveAs('/your/directory/'.$file->name);
```

Comment: this is just an example. you can put condition if $filel null

Comment: I know, that I can do this. I only inform you, that your code contains a serious bug. I can't (shouldn't) edit your answer and fix it myself, because etiquette at Stack Overflow forces to use edit only to fix minor bugs. And when there is a bug in code, its author should be notified and asked to do fix manually. That's what I did.

Answer (score 6):

Create a read only attribute for your model like `public $image`and proceed like

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'image')->fileInput() ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I really like [Yii2 Dropzone](https://github.com/perminder-klair/yii2-dropzone#yii2-dropzone).

Installation:

```
composer require --prefer-dist perminder-klair/yii2-dropzone "dev-master"
```

Usage:

```
<?php 
    echo \kato\DropZone::widget([
       'options' => [
           'url'=> Url::to(['resource-manager/upload']),
           'paramName'=>'image',
           'maxFilesize' => '10',
       ],
       'clientEvents' => [
           'complete' => "function(file){console.log(file)}",
           'removedfile' => "function(file){alert(file.name + ' is removed')}"
       ],
   ]);

   ?>
```

Controller:

```
public function actionUpload(){

        $model = new ResourceManager();
        $uploadPath = Yii::getAlias('@root') .'/uploads/';

        if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {
            $file = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('image');
          $original_name = $file->baseName;  
          $newFileName = \Yii::$app->security
                            ->generateRandomString().'.'.$file->extension;
           // you can write save code here before uploading.
            if ($file->saveAs($uploadPath . '/' . $newFileName)) {
                $model->image = $newFileName;
                $model->original_name = $original_name;
                if($model->save(false)){
                    echo \yii\helpers\Json::encode($file);
                }
                else{
                    echo \yii\helpers\Json::encode($model->getErrors());
                }

            }
        }
        else {
            return $this->render('upload', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

give this code after your uploaded code

```
  //save the path in DB..
                $model->file = 'uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension;
                $model->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one file while uploading you must use foreach for that. And you should actual name of file in a column in table and a encrypted value of that name has to be stored to avoid duplicated in the directory.. Something like this..

```
$userdocs->document_name = UploadedFile::getInstances($userdocs, 'document_name');

foreach ($userdocs->document_name as $key => $file) {
  $img_name = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
  $file->saveAs('user/business_files/' . $img_name . '.' . $file->extension);
  $images = $img_name . '.' . $file->extension;
  $userdocs->actual_name = $file->name;
  $userdocs->user_id = $user->id;
  $userdocs->document_name = $images;
  $userdocs->save(false);
  $userdocs = new UserDocs();
}
```

Here a random string is generated and it will be assign with the name of the document, and it will be stored in the table. The **UserDocs** is the model name.