# How to upload files in root folder in yii2 advanced template?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am unable to upload files in root folder.

I uploaded files in root folder and access these files in frontend and backend
application.

Comment: Maybe you can not upload to root folder, but anyway you can access files from frontend and backend both, that depends on how you configure your urls on production

Comment: if you are in linux you need to give access to apache to root folder with in `chown -R www-data:www-data /root`

Comment: do you actually meen the /root folder or do you mean the "root" (main) folder of the application?

Comment: @Bharat - Below answer is write you can upload your files from backend in frontend/web/upload folder and you can access that uploaded images on frontend

Comment: @zazu I'm getting this error: `finfo_file(/tmp/phpGjxsrP): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`. Is this permission issue? how I can give permission to `tmp` directory. I'm using ubuntu(15.10)

Answer (score 4):

When using the advanced template you need to decide on a common place to store your files that can be accessed by both the frontend and backend application, additionally if you want the files to be publicly accessible via the web you need to insure this location is a public folder.

I tend to use the frontend/web folder as my common upload location. When uploading from the backend I write to this location. I can then use the images in the frontend.

Example uploading form the backend.

**UploadForm.php**

Create a model to manage the upload data, make sure to include the file attribute.

```
class UploadForm extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var UploadedFile file attribute
     */
    public $file;

    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['file'], 'file', 'extensions'=>'jpg, gif, png'],
        ];
    }
}
```

**UploadController**

In the controller that will be managing the upload use the alias for the frontend to set your upload path `$path = Yii::getAlias('@frontend') .'/web/uploads/'`

```
class MediaController extends Controller
{

    public function actionIndex()
    {

        $model = new UploadForm();

        //Set the path that the file will be uploaded to
        $path = Yii::getAlias('@frontend') .'/web/upload/'

        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
            $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');

            if ($model->file && $model->validate()) {
                $model->file->saveAs($path . $model->file->baseName . '.' . $model->file->extension);
            }
        }

        return $this->renderPartial('index', ['model' => $model]);

    }
}
```

**View Form**

Add a form to your view, make sure to set the `'multipart/form-data'` enctype so that it can accept file uploads.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput(); ?>

    <?= Html::submitButton('Upload') ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

**Front End**

You can then access the image in the front end via /upload/{image-name}.{extension}.  example `<img src="/upload/sample.png">`

Note: it is a good idea to store your upload path in the common/config/params.php so that you can access from both frontend and backend.

Answer (score 3):

Here is complete solution of image uploading,updating, deleting an image.
Please follow the steps carefully.

#### 1 Create `uploads` folder in your root directory.

#### 2 Root Alias in Yii2

Open you common/config/bootstrap.php and add this line top of the file

```
Yii::setAlias('@root', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../'));

---
```

#### 3 Model:

```
public function rules()
    {
    return [

        ['image', 'image', 
                    'skipOnEmpty' => true, 
                    'extensions' => 'jpg, gif, png']

        ];
    }
```

#### 4 File Input

```
<?php
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'image')->fileInput() ?>

    <button>Submit</button>

<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

#### 5 Controller action

```
 class PostController extends Controller
   {
       public function actionCreate()
       {
        $model = new Post();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {            
            $file = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
            if (!empty($file))
                $model->image = $file;

            if($model->save())
            {
             if (!empty($file))
              $file->saveAs( Yii::getAlias('@root') .'/uploads/' . $file);

              return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            }
            return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model]);
        }
       }

       public function actionUpdate($id)
       {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){           
            $file = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
           if (!empty($file)){
                 $delete = $model->oldAttributes['image'];
                 $model->image= $file; 
            }
            else{
                $model->image = $model->oldAttributes['image'];
            }
            if($model->save())
            {
             if (!empty($file))
              $file->saveAs( Yii::getAlias('@root') .'/uploads/' . $file);

              return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            }
            return $this->render('update', ['model' => $model]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', ['model' => $model]);
        }
    }

       public function actionDelete($id)
       {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        if(file_exists(Yii::getAlias('@root') . '/uploads/'. $model->image))
        unlink(Yii::getAlias('@root') . '/uploads/'. $model->image);
        $model->delete(); 
         return $this->redirect(['index']);
       }

  }
```

### Edit:

#### 6 Show in Gridview(Backend)

```
[
'attribute' => 'image',
'format' => 'html',    
'value' => function ($data) {
    return Html::img('../../../uploads/'. $data['image'],
        ['width' => '70px']);
 },
],
```

#### 7 Show in DetailView(Backend)

```
   [
      'attribute'=>'image',
      'label'=> 'Post Picture',
      'value'=> '../../../uploads/' . $model->image,
      'format'=>['image',['width'=>100, 'height'=>100]]
    ],
```

if you have hide frontend/web then add this rule in your project root (yii2-app) .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(uploads)
  RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ uploads/$1 [L]
```

#### Show image in frontend

```
 <img src="<?php echo 'uploads/'.$model->image; ?>">
```

Comment: I am able to upload files but unable to see them in view. What can be a problem?

Comment: how you are displaying image in view? share your code. try something this: `Yii::getAlias('@root') .'/uploads/' . $model->image`

Comment: `<?php echo Html::img('../../uploads/ring.jpg',['class' => 'img-center', 'width'=>150, 'heigth'=>150, 'alt'=>'no image']) ?>`. I tried also with getAlias - no success. Is there might be some restrictions in folders? My OS is Windows 10.

Comment: Probably your DocumentRoot in your Webserver is www/yiiapplication/. But I have it www/yiiapplication/backend/web. Do not you now how to access www/yiiapplication/uploads in this case?

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad, In view files with gridview not abe to load the images as you mentioned above steps. Getting 404 error while accessing the images in new tab.

Comment: where you store images? what is your root .htaccess?

Comment: I've stored images in root directory as your steps followed. And also I've separated the front & back end urls using .htaccess only.

Comment: have you added this in you root .htaccess file? `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(uploads)
  RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ uploads/$1 [L]`

Comment: @MuhammadShnahzad, Its working fine now. Your answer is accepted