# Yii 2.0: How To configuring file upload and access for backend and frontend in Yii2 advanced app

Tags: file-upload, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i have uploads file in yii2 advance app.
but, one problem found.
i have uploads file in "backend/web/uploads". but, not access in frontend.
so, how to uploads & access file in common directory.

Comment: show your controller/action code

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload files in root folder in yii2 advanced template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28493615/how-to-upload-files-in-root-folder-in-yii2-advanced-template)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily access backend/web/uploads from the frontend, you just have to use the @backend path alias.