# Adding an image upload field to signup form in yii2 when creating an account

Tags: php, yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app

Am creating a signup form in yii2 which requires one to upload his/her own image and save the link in the database

In the view signup form i have

```
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'username') ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>

            <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput() ?>
            <div class="form-group">
<?= Html::submitButton('Signup', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'signup-button']) ?>
            </div>
        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

In the signup controller

```
 public function actionSignup()
{
    $model = new SignupForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        if ($user = $model->signup()) {

            if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {
                return $this->goHome();
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->render('signup', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

In the model signup form i have:

```
public function signup()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        $user = new User();
                 $imageName = $user->username;
                 $user->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($user,'file');
                 $user->file->saveAs( 'uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension );
                $user->picture =  'uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension; 


        $user->username = $this->username;
        $user->email = $this->email;
        $user->setPassword($this->password);
        $user->generateAuthKey();
        if ($user->save()) {
            return $user;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

But i keep on getting an error that Class 'frontend\models\UploadedFile' not found and cannot save the image to the database

Comment: You imported the class into the model? `use yii\web\UploadedFile;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload a file to directory in yii2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23592125/how-to-upload-a-file-to-directory-in-yii2)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `UploadedFile` to `\yii\web\UploadedFile` or write after `namespace`

`use \yii\web\UploadedFile`

Comment: Onedev.Link it worked but i get the error : Setting unknown property: common\models\User::file

Comment: Propably you need replace `file` to `picture`, or add to model `public $file;` string. [See example](http://blog.ituri.net/2015/01/how-to-upload-a-file-in-yii2/).

Comment: It works that way i replaced the file to picture and i still get an error that Call to a member function saveAs() on a non-object

Comment: `saveAs()` you should call only for `UploadedFile` object. If `picture` is field with picture name in database, make sure that model have public property `public $file;`, or use local variable `$file` instead `$user->file`.