# can't upload image in yii2 using kartik widget

Tags: yii2

This is my controller i am get confused so let me know what is mistake new here

```
 $imgName = $model->uploadimg;
            $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'uploadimg');
            $model->file->saveAS('uploads/'.$imgName.'.'.$model->file->extension);
            $model->uplaodimg='uploads/'.$imgName.'.'.$model->file->extension;

 This is view 
echo $form->field($model, 'uploadimg')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*'],
]);
```

Comment: so any errors ?

Comment: uploadimg can't  not be blank

Comment: [This will help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23592125/how-to-upload-a-file-to-directory-in-yii2)

Comment: have you checked your data submitted by your form? whether it contains image data

Answer (score 1):

Set `Activeform`'s option `enctype` to `multipart/form-data` as follows:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'options' => ['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']
]); ?>
```

Comment: @arogachev: thanks for formatting. I will take care of it now onwards :)

Answer (score 0):

View:

```php
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

<?= $form->field($model, 'uploadimg')->fileInput(['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/']) ?>
```

Controller:

```php
public function actionCreate()
{
        $model = new Model_Name();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $model->uploadimg = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'uploadimg');
            $model->save();                
        }
}
```