# How to upload image in the yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have one problem in yii2 when I use

```
$model = Client::find()->where('id=1')->one();
UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'logo');
```

then this `gitme NULL` value. Why am I getting `NULL` if I print `$_FILES` and them I see the array values.
I have use the simple upload file in yii2

My view :

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' => ['center/updatelogo'], 'layout' => 'horizontal', 'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]);
echo $form->field($model, 'logo')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'options' => ['accept' => $model->logo, 'class' => 'form-control'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowedFileExtensions' => ['png', 'jpg'],
        'maxFileSize' => 25000,
    ],
]);
```

My controller:

```
$model = Client::find()->where('id=1')->one();
if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
    $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'logo');
    if ($model->validate()) {
        $model->file->saveAs('logos/' . $model->file->baseName . '.' . $model->file->extension);
    }
}
var_dump($file);die();
```

I need upload one file to mi server and put the logo, what happened?

my $_POST and my $_FILES :

```
array(2) {
  ["_csrf"]=>
  string(88) "WF67odQ_DUylcUprRN9FssjEdq5nBn2ARrjjql_D8af6Y1am1ID7AEG5KV2iWNL-7QeEoeGF_UJQYxnH6JgS1A=="
  ["Center"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["logo"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}

array(1) {
  ["Center"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["logo"]=>
      string(19) "Libre Albedrío.jpg"
    }
    ["type"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["logo"]=>
      string(10) "image/jpeg"
    }
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["logo"]=>
      string(14) "/tmp/phpYijyXv"
    }
    ["error"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["logo"]=>
      int(0)
    }
    ["size"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["logo"]=>
      int(19900)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, edit your question and give your $_POST and $_FILES values, please

Comment: Are you sure that `'accept'` option sould be `$model->logo` but not `'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*']`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload a file to directory in yii2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23592125/how-to-upload-a-file-to-directory-in-yii2)

Comment: I change options how @AntonRybalko , but dont work for me ,what Im doing wrong??

Comment: Have you defined `[['logo'], 'file']` in rules method of model

Comment: @andrwsv. Check for folder permissions, Try to give 777 permission to folder

Comment: `$model->file->saveAs()` return True when the file is saved successfully. you can check if this is the case first. Then you can use `getHasError ( )`  and `$model->file->error`to check for errors in the uploaded file.

Comment: yes @Mohan I have defined in my model  [['logo'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],